# Webapp Logback Logging Does Not Work Using Tomee Plus 1.6.0 on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, web-applications, logback, apache-tomee

I am able to get logback logging to work correctly on my development environment (Windows) using Tomee 1.6.0.1; however, whenever I try to deploy the webapp on my Tomee server on Linux, it never creates the "test.app.log" file specified in the logback.xml configuration file inside of the WEB-INF/classes directory of the webapp.

Using maven, I have included logback-classic-1.1.2 and logback-core-1.1.2 in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the webapp.

I double check permissions for the directory to which I wish to write (CATALINA_BASE/logs), but it is set to rw for all users so I doubt that is the problem.

No matter what I try, all of my logs keep getting pushed to catalina.out. Can anybody solve the mystery as to why logging with logback works correctly on Windows (development environment) but not Linux?

Comment: what does your localhost/catlina.out log says about loading logback classes and init of logback

Comment: SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

Comment: It's weird because I do not see those logs on Windows, where it works.

Comment: Hello. Is there anybody out there? :P

Comment: Is it possible that by adding a <Deployment dir> tag in the conf/tomee.xml file, it somehow causes the WEB-INF/lib to no longer be included in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we were separating our EJB's into another directory and adding that directory as a "Deployment dir" in tomee.xml. This unhooks the webapp independent logging.

Romain, from Tomee fame, suggested I use either VirtualWebappLoader or jars.txt implementations.